# Neural Network: change input instead of the network

Tags: python, pybrain

Firstly, sorry for my english which is not very good but still understandable (i hope).

What i want to do is to change my input instead of the weigths of my neural network to reduce the error. 
I was wondering if it was possible? i think that we can use the backpropagation algorithm to do such a thing. 
To do this, i'm using pybrain (a python library) and i don't know if there's a way to do it

So if you have any advice, or if you have an idea of how i can do it with pybrain, please let me know

Comment: Sure you can, getting good training data is imperative. But you obviously shouldn't overtrain. How are you measuring your error?

Comment: Changing the weights is the whole purpose of backpropagation. Why would you not want to change the weights? Random initialization of the weights is as a good as just making a random decision

Comment: My goal is not to get good training data. I want to change my training data to fit them to them to the neural network. My error is the difference between the target value (let's say Y) and the output of my neural network (as often). I know it don't seems to be natural but it's totally possible to do such a thing (mathematically) 

The classical backpropagation algorithm change the weights to reduce the error, what i want to do is to change the input (the training data) for reducing this error

Comment: Changing your input on every feedforward would be incredibly slow and not scale very well since the input is very dynamic.

Comment: Yes i know, but i still want to try this, the scaling is not my first problem

Comment: I just would like to know why you are changing the input? It really does not make any sense to do so. There is no well defined mathematical way of doing this, since the input will vary enormously and changing your input will just perform horribly for future data points. But who knows, this may be the next greatest thing. Try it out, let us know how it goes.

Comment: I'm not trying to find any great thing, and i'm not using neural networks to perform in machine learming in this case. My neural network is just a mathematical function f, and i want to find the best X like f(x)=y. My english is not perfect and it's hard to explain why i want to do this, but it's just for my research
I just wanted help for doing this with pybrain

Comment: Completely possible, but not with pybrain. Doable with backprop in a pretty trivial way.

Comment: @AlejandroLucena There is actually an extremely well-defined mathematical way of doing this, it's just the same as backprop.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. If you have more details or advices on how i must proceed, ie what are exactly the changes on the classical backpropagation algorithm, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use backpropagation to change the input to the neural network instead of the weights. The resulting [delta rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_rule) is almost identical to that of the standard error backpropagation algorithm, but instead of multiplying by the input, you multiply by the weight:

[image: delta]

For simplicity, consider a SISO network with a single perceptron.
[image: single perceptron SISO network]

Just as you might derive the change in weight w using gradient descent, we can do the same for a change in input u:

[image: ex]